# Python printing extra content

Tags: python

Why is the following code printing "None" at the end?

```
class Square:
  def printx(self):
    print "A"

test = Square()
print test.printx()
```

Output:

```
A
None
```

Why isn't it just printing only the letter "A"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `printx`, the `print` statement there prints "A". Then the method ends, and returns a `None`, that's what the `print` statement in the last line prints.

You can fix it as such -

```
class Square:
  def printx(self):
    print "A"

test = Square()
test.printx()
```

OR

```
class Square:
  def printx(self):
    return "A"

test = Square()
print test.printx()
```

Although based on the semantics, the first option would make more sense.

Comment: I'd change the member function in the second method to the name ``getx()`` to explain the semantics of what you're doing.

Answer (score 5):

Because you have two `print` statements. You're printing the 'A' as well as the return value of `printx`.